# Problemas ao preencher campos no PDF em asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou com problemas ao **renderizar** alguns campos da minha tabela no arquivo **PDF**. Estava funcionando direitinho, mas não sei o que aconteceu que esses campos **não estão mais** renderizando. Na minha tela **Meus Cursos**, o **aluno** tem um botão que ele emite uma **Declaração de Conclusão de Curso**, mas quando o aluno clica no botão e gera o **PDF** os campos vem **sem dados**.
Obs.: Os dados que devem **renderizar** no PDF são: **Nome do Aluno**, **Matricula**, **Nome do Curso**, **Período** e **Carga Horária**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**View PDF**

```html
@model MeuProjeto.Models.AlunoCurso
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href="~/Content/PDF.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title>GeraPDF</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br/> <br/>

    <div id="declaracao">
        <strong style="font-family: 'Times New Roman'">Declaração de Conclusão de Curso</strong>
    </div>

<br/>
<hr/>

<text style="font-family: 'Times New Roman'; font-size: 20px">
    Declaramos que o Sr(a). <b>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Aluno.Nome)</b>, matrícula de Nº <b>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Aluno.Matricula)</b>,
    inscrito no curso de <b>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Curso.Nome_Curso)</b>, na XXXXX,
    no período de <b>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Curso.Dt_Inicio)</b> a <b>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Curso.Dt_Fim)</b>,
    cumprindo uma carga horária de <b>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Curso.Carga_Horaria)</b>, com total comprometimento e dedicação todos os requisitos para a conclusão deste curso,
    estamos encaminhando esta via de Declaração para que seja emitido junta a XXXXXX, o
    <b>Certificado</b> de conclusão de Curso.
</text>

<hr/>

<div id="assinatura">
    _________________________ <span>em</span><span> ___/___/_____</span><br/>
    Assinatura do Responsável
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Action PDF**

```
public ActionResult GerarPDF(int id)
    {
        var alunoCurso = db.AlunoCursos.FirstOrDefault(ac => ac.Aluno.Usuario == User.Identity.Name);
        if (alunoCurso != null)
        {
            AlunoCurso aluno =
                db.AlunoCursos.Include(a => a.Aluno).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(al => al.AlunoId == id);

            var pdf = new ViewAsPdf
            {
                ViewName = "GeraPDF",
                FileName = "Declaração.pdf",
                Model = aluno,
                PageSize = Size.A4,
                PageMargins = new Margins {Bottom = 2, Left = 2, Right = 2, Top = 2}
            };

            return pdf;
        }

        return View();
    }
```

**Trecho da minha View com o botão que Chama o PDF**

```html
@model IEnumerable<MeuProjeto.Models.AlunoCurso>

<!-- Aqui é BOTÃO onde chama a página do PDF -->

<div class="btn-group">
<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
 @if (item.Aprovado == false)
  {
   <input type="submit" value="Pendente de Aprovação" name="meusCursos" class="cursos btn btn-primary btn-sm" disabled="disabled" data-id="@item.Id" />
  }
  else
  {
  <a href="~/AlunoCursos/GerarPDF?id=@item.Id" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span></a>
  }
  </div>
  </div>

@section Scripts {
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $(".cursos").click(function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "MeusCursos/",
                            data: { id: $(this).data("id") },
                            success: function () {
                                $(this).attr("enable", "enable");
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Comment: Já tentou colocar *breakpoints* na *View* pra verificar o estado das variáveis de *Model*?

Comment: Coloquei @CiganoMorrisonMendez, não tá trazendo nada. O engraçado é que estava funcionando, e agora não sei o que houve. Pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conseguir resolver da seguinte forma: **Na minha Action não alterei nada**

```
public ActionResult GerarPDF(int id)
    {
        //Aqui eu pego o usuário logado
        var alunoCurso = db.AlunoCursos.FirstOrDefault(ac => ac.Aluno.Usuario == User.Identity.Name);
        if (alunoCurso != null)
        {
            //Aqui eu faço o include do aluno e pego o AlunoID
            AlunoCurso aluno =
                db.AlunoCursos.Include(a => a.Aluno).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(al => al.AlunoId == id);

            var pdf = new ViewAsPdf
            {
                ViewName = "GeraPDF",
                FileName = "Declaração.pdf",
                Model = aluno,
                PageSize = Size.A4,
                PageMargins = new Margins {Bottom = 2, Left = 2, Right = 2, Top = 2}
            };

            return pdf;
        }

        return View();
    }
```

**Aqui o código do botão que chama a Action PDF**

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
   @if (item.Aprovado == false)
    {
      <input type="submit" value="Pendente de Aprovação" name="meusCursos" class="cursos btn btn-primary btn-sm" disabled="disabled" data-id="@item.Id" />
              }
              else
              {
                              <!-- Aqui nessa linha que DEVE SER FEITA A ALTERAÇÃO -->
               <a href="~/AlunoCursos/GerarPDF?id=@item.Id" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Emitir Declaração</a>
              }
              </div>
```

**A alteração deve ser feita no @item.Id**, como precisava pegar o ID do aluno o correto é passar o **AlunoId**.

```html
<div class="btn-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
     @if (item.Aprovado == false)
     {
      <input type="submit" value="Pendente de Aprovação" name="meusCursos" class="cursos btn btn-primary btn-sm" disabled="disabled" data-id="@item.Id" />
              }
              else
              {
                 <!-- Só trocar o @item.Id por @item.AlunoId -->
               <a href="~/AlunoCursos/GerarPDF?id=@item.AlunoId" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Emitir Declaração</a>
              }
              </div>
```

Desta forma os campos no PDF serão preenchidos.

Answer (score 0):

Não tenho certeza se é isso, mas não use `@Html.DisplayFor()` com o Rotativa. O Rotativa é um pacote esquisito e cheio de problemas. Troque pela menção direta da variável, conforme abaixo:

```
<text style="font-family: 'Times New Roman'; font-size: 20px">
    Declaramos que o Sr(a). <b>@Model.Aluno.Nome</b>, matrícula de Nº <b>@Model.Aluno.Matricula</b>,
    inscrito no curso de <b>@Model.Curso.Nome_Curso</b>, na XXXXX,
    no período de <b>@Model.Curso.Dt_Inicio</b> a <b>@Model.Curso.Dt_Fim</b>,
    cumprindo uma carga horária de <b>@Model.Curso.Carga_Horaria</b>, com total comprometimento e dedicação todos os requisitos para a conclusão deste curso,
    estamos encaminhando esta via de Declaração para que seja emitido junta a XXXXXX, o
    <b>Certificado</b> de conclusão de Curso.
</text>
```

---

**EDIT**

Acho que você está usando a chave errada pra selecionar. Modifique o código abaixo:

```
AlunoCurso aluno =
            db.AlunoCursos.Include(a => a.Aluno).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(al => al.AlunoId == id);
```

Para:

```
var alunoCurso =
            db.AlunoCursos.Include(a => a.Aluno).FirstOrDefault(ac => ac.AlunoCursoId == id);
```

Comment: Eu acho que o problema é aqui `AlunoCurso aluno = db.AlunoCursos.Include(a => a.Aluno).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(al => al.AlunoId == id);` por que o **aluno** tá vindo `null`. Mas não consegui arrumar.

Comment: @Novato Por favor, poderia escrever uma resposta, esclarecendo como foi feito, pelo benefício da comunidade?

Comment: Ainda não consegui arrumar o erro @CiganoMorrisonMendez, só descobri ao `debugar` que o **aluno** desse trecho de código `AlunoCurso aluno = db.AlunoCursos.Include(a => a.Aluno).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(al => al.AlunoId == id);` está vindo **nulo**, mas ainda não sei o porque.

Comment: @Novato Atualizei a resposta. Veja se te atende.

Comment: Não dei certo @CiganoMorrisonMendez, porque a declaração deve ser emitida pelo usuário que está logado, igual eu fiz aqui `var alunoCurso = db.AlunoCursos.FirstOrDefault(ac => ac.Aluno.Usuario == User.Identity.Name);
        if (alunoCurso != null)`. Ai dentro do `if` ele não aceitou esse seu trecho.

Comment: Como assim, "não aceitou esse seu trecho"? Seja mais claro. Não responda com "não deu certo". Diga exatamente o que aconteceu, com a mensagem de erro. Eu não vejo sua tela. Ler "não deu certo" não vai fazer eu te ajudar com qualidade.

Comment: Continua vindo `nulo` @CiganoMorrisonMendez.